# Remove (hide) mouse cursor when idle on Rasbperry Pi OS Bookworm

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

There are many similar questions (e. g. [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/how-to-permanently-hide-mouse-pointer-or-cursor-on-raspberry-pi), and on the forums), but all the answers are outdated - they are for `xserver`, `lightdm`, `lxde` etc., and not for Bookworm/Wayland.

So, how can we hide the mouse cursor in the latest Bookworm RPi OS? `unclutter` from `apt` doesn't work, it does nothing (the cursor never hides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wayfire itself doesn't come with this feature bundled, but can be easily extended through its complementary `wayfire-plugins-extra` package. Unfortunately, it is not available in the Bookworm repos.

I (very) recently had a similar requirement for a project and came up with a solution. You can find my [full entry here](https://gist.github.com/seffs/2395ca640d6d8d8228a19a9995418211). I'll pick what is relevant for your question:

#### Hide mouse pointer

##### 1) Install wayfire-plugins-extra

Compiled Library:

1. Download the correct library for your architecture from [here](https://github.com/seffs/wayfire-plugins-extra-raspbian/releases) *(Compiled by me. Feel free to build from source)*
2. Decompress with `tar xf /path/to/wayfire-plugins-extra-raspbian-<your-arch>.tar.xz`
3. Each plugin comes with .so and .xml files. You will need to copy those to their correct paths:
   `sudo cp <desired-plugin>.so /usr/lib/<your-arch-linux-gnu>/wayfire/<desired-plugin>.so`
   `sudo cp <desired-plugin>.xml /usr/share/wayfire/metadata/<desired-plugin>.xml`

Build from Source:

1. Follow the instructions in https://github.com/seffs/wayfire-plugins-extra/. Install all required dev packages with
   `sudo apt install libglibmm-2.4-dev libglm-dev libxml2-dev libpango1.0-dev libcairo2-dev wayfire-dev libwlroots-dev libwf-config-dev meson ninja-build`
2. Each plugin comes with .so and .xml files. `meson` should take care of the installation. Otherwise check if the following path exists for any new extra plugin:
   `ls /usr/lib/<your-arch-linux-gnu>/wayfire/<new-extra-plugin>.so`
   `ls /usr/share/wayfire/metadata/<new-extra-plugin>.xml`

##### 2) Activate your plugin(s)

I was only interested in hiding the mouse pointer. This can be accomplished with the `hide_cursor` plugin. The same concept applies to the rest of plugins.

Open your `~/.config/wayfire.init` file and adjust the following:

```ini
[core]
plugins = \
        autostart \
        ### We need to add the extra plugin to the list ###
        hide-cursor
```

Launch wayfire once again. You'll notice that the mouse pointer disappeared.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A small typo: "Open your ~/.config/wayfire.init file and adjust the following:" The file is wyfire.ini, at least in on my pi.

ps. thanks alot! :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134433)