# How do I hide the cursor in Raspberry Pi OS (Debian 12 Bookworm)

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I'm setting up a dashboard computer using a Raspberry Pi 5 installed with Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit (Debian 12 Bookworm).

So far I've gotten it up and running with starting Chromium in fullscreen, kiosk mode with my dashboard on it, which works great.

However, I simply can't figure out how to hide the cursor that shows up in the middle of the screen by default. Most commonly, [`unclutter` is recommended](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=234879) but no matter where I put `unclutter -idle 0`, it doesn't seem to have any effect. Even running it directly from the command line on the Pi via a terminal opened after booting to the desktop, does nothing. It's the same behavior no matter if my autostart of Chromium is there or not.

I've also tried adding `xserver-command = X -nocursor` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as suggested [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/how-to-permanently-hide-mouse-pointer-or-cursor-on-raspberry-pi) but that has no effect either.

The ideal scenario is to only have the cursor hidden on inactivity but I'd greatly appreciate any pointers in the right direction.